# How to Open a New Window Even if the Pop-up Blocker Is Turned On in GWT/GXT?

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am using GWT / GXT in my application.

My functionality working is as follows.

1. I have a button.
2. On click of the button there is a url which should get opened in a new tab.
3. Currently on click of button The Url is not opened in a new tab as I have my browser configured to block the popups.

Can anyone suggest a way where I can bypass the popup blocking and open url in new tab anyway??

How Can I achieve this in GWT/GXT framework.

Comment: Please take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277752/gwt-open-window-after-rpc-is-prevented-by-popup-blocker).

Comment: I'd probably use a GXT window which is an absolutely positioned div and it wouldn't fall under opening another window to be blocked. Do you need to use another browser window, or could you use the existing window?